# Only third div column not positioning properly?

Tags: html, css

I have three columns on my page, left, middle and right. The left and the middle ones are positionnig fine across browsers. BUt the far right one does not position properly, if i give it the same margin-top:30px (just as the other divs have) it goes way down the screen?

Thanks for any suggestions

css:

```
    #firstColumn
{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:30px;
    float:left;

}

#secondColumn
{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:315px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:30px;
    float:none;

}

#thirdColumn
{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:650px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    float:none;

}
```

html:

```
<div id="firstColumn">
<p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray;"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></p>
<hr style="background-color:Gray; border:0.5px solid Gray" />
<p style="color:Blue; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div id="secondColumn" >
<p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray;"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></p>
<hr style="background-color:Gray; border:0.5px solid Gray" />
<p style="color:Blue; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div id="thirdColumn" >
<p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray;"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></p>
<hr style="background-color:Gray; border:0.5px solid Gray" />
<p style="color:Blue; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not simply wrap them in a container with a set width and then float them to the left of eachother?

Answer (score 0):

Spot the mistake: `margin-top:-30px;` at `#thirdColumn` in the CSS.

Edit: Use `position:absolute;`

Edit #2:

```
#firstColumn {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:30px;
    float:left;
}

#secondColumn {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:315px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:30px;
    float:none;
}

#thirdColumn {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:650px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:30px;
    float:none;
}

<div id="firstColumn"></div>
<div id="secondColumn" ></div>
<div id="thirdColumn" ></div>
```

Comment: Ah no sorry that is a typo, it is not like that in my css sorry

Comment: All of the divs should be positioned next to each other, with a small gap between them. Only the first two divs are doing this

Comment: In my browser (firefox) the two columns aren't in a row.
Did you try `position:absolute;`? For me it's working now, all in a row.

Comment: What all three are in a row? Could you please post the html and css for me so i can take a look at it?

Comment: No that has not done it sorry, if you checked it in IE then the divs appear to be going in a stair formation?

Comment: sorry, I have linux, I can't check that out.

Answer (score 0):

To easily get the layout you are after a structure like below which would easily do the trick;

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="entry"><!-- Your stuff --></div>
    <div class="entry"><!-- Your stuff --></div>
    <div class="entry"><!-- Your stuff --></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {width: 600px;} /* The overall width you want */
#container .entry {width: 190px; float: left; margin: 0 5px;}
```

A working example http://jsfiddle.net/CarlG/dpM2T/

Comment: thankyou, this works to an extent. But the desired affect that I want is that they are next to each other going horizontally across the oage. This goes vertically? how would i get it to go horizontally

Comment: This does not go vertically check the jsfiddle in the answer

Comment: I just put together a similar jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YMsYw/2/
note that with floated layouts like this you should probably familiarize yourself with the "clearfix", and the box-model in general.

My fiddle also uses better-accepted ways of styling your content. Inline CSS and un-semantic html are so 90's ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Right I have solved it now, what i did in the end was wrap each column in its own div and positioned that. Thankyou everyone for their suggestions and advice!